# Hardware that can generate chirp audio signal

Tags: arduino, audio, speakers, hardware

Basically I would like to generate chirp audio signal that sweeps from 16 kHz to 18 kHz, the signal lasts about 100 ms, no restrict requirements on the sound volume. I am able to generate such chirp signal as the control signal using Arduino, I would like to have an external hardware connecting to Arduino which converts the control signal to the corresponding chirp sound wave.

Essentially the external hardware should be able to be controlled by the Arduino and generate customized audio signals.

Any recommendations on such hardware? It would be better if it's an audio module already on the market

TIA!

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like a prohibited *shopping question*.  It's also very short on specifications, eg, what sort of purity do you require of your chirp?  You can probably do it to a degree using PWM output from a timer on the Arduino's ATmega, but some ARM MCU with a DAC might be cleaner.  Your signal is only marginally "audio"...

Comment: There are plenty of "DDS" (direct digital synthesis) modules that could generate such a signal.

Comment: Sorry, but I answered my question myself. Let me know if I need to delete this thread

Comment: It would have been an interesting matter to discuss how to make such a synthesizer from scratch. But the asker doesn't seem to have interest in that. I'm not normally for deleting questions, but this one is a bummer.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow I modified my answer where I mentioned that I don't have much knowledge and resources of making my own customized hardware. So I would like to have sth that is like an "All-in-one", "ready-to-use". Sorry I didn't ask in a clear way

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 out-of-box audio modules which can fit my requirements: UDA1334A, PCM5102A.

I don't have much knowledge and resources of making my own hardware, these two audio modules integrate DAC, filter, audio jack etc. Additionally they support frequency from 20 Hz-20 kHz. UDA1334A is a 16-bit DAC I2S audio module while PCM5102A is a 32-bit one, they are able to provide enough resolutions for me.

Most importantly, they are out-of-box, ready-to-use modules, since they are equipped with all necessary devices on the board.

Comment: You may find generating an I2S signal with an Arduino, at least an ATmega-based one, is not trivial.  It probably *can* be done with some usage of the hardware normally used for SPI but you will need to be careful as an Audio DAC typically bases its conversion on the clock, so any jitter there will show up in your output, potentially even as spurious frequency content.  I think you might have better luck seeing if there's a SAMD-based Arduino or a Teensy with an on-board DAC that could do the whole job without involving I2S.